# Access table not updating when using Do While OleDbDataReader.Read loop

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB.net coding and had design a code which will read a column of a table through `Do While OleDbDataReader.Read` loop for every row in table and update the column `mont` where is is not Zero.

The code is running without any error but when I open the table to see the changes, they are not there, i.e. if we pass the value through

```
tempMontComputer (Integer)
```

But if I directly place the value in SQL query i.e. instead of using

```
SET mont = @mont
```

use

```
SET mont = 55
```

the value is stored and the table is updated.

Table consists of columns

- `emp_id` (Text)
- `emp_name` (Text)
- `emp_comp_amt` (Number)
- `installment` (Number)
- `mont` (Number)

This is my code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO

Public provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
Public databasepath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\EMPLOYEES.accdb"
Public connString As String = provider & databasepath
Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

Public cmdUpdateAdvCompu As New OleDbCommand
Public DRAdvComputer As OleDbDataReader
Public tempMontComputer As Integer

Private Sub frmCalculateData_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()

Dim commandAdvComputer As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM adv_computer", myConnection)
DRAdvComputer = commandAdvComputer.ExecuteReader()

Do WhileDRAdvComputer.Read
    If DRAdvComputer.Item("emp_comp_amt") <> 0 And DRAdvComputer.Item("mont") <> 0 Then
            nscd_emp_comp_adv = DRAdvComputer.Item("emp_comp_amt") / DRAdvComputer.Item("installment")
            tempMontComputer = DRAdvComputer.Item("mont") - 2
            cmdUpdateAdvCompu.CommandText = "UPDATE adv_computer SET mont = @mont WHERE emp_id = @ID"
            cmdUpdateAdvCompu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", DRAdvComputer.Item("emp_id"))
            cmdUpdateAdvCompu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mont", tempMontComputer)
            cmdUpdateAdvCompu.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmdUpdateAdvCompu.Connection = myConnection
            cmdUpdateAdvCompu.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
Loop

cmdUpdateCheckDate.Dispose()
cmdUpdateAdvCompu.Dispose()
myConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In OleDb parameters are not recognized by their name but by their position.
You add the `@ID` parameter before the `@mont` parameter and thus the two values are swapped when applied to the parameter placeholders. This gives you an incorrect query where the code attempts to set the mont field with the value of the @ID parameter and the ID field used in the WHERE statement with the value  @mont parameter. So you don't update anything or, for happenstance, you update the wrong record.

Just reverse the parameter order:

```
Do WhileDRAdvComputer.Read
    If DRAdvComputer.Item("emp_comp_amt") <> 0 And DRAdvComputer.Item("mont") <> 0 Then
            nscd_emp_comp_adv = DRAdvComputer.Item("emp_comp_amt") / DRAdvComputer.Item("installment")
            tempMontComputer = DRAdvComputer.Item("mont") - 2
            cmdUpdateAdvCompu.CommandText = "UPDATE adv_computer SET mont = @mont WHERE emp_id = @ID"
            cmdUpdateAdvCompu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mont", tempMontComputer)
            cmdUpdateAdvCompu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", DRAdvComputer.Item("emp_id"))
            cmdUpdateAdvCompu.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmdUpdateAdvCompu.Connection = myConnection
            cmdUpdateAdvCompu.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
Loop
```